# нужна помощь с SASS

Tags: css, sass, sublime-text, emmet

Ребят, перешел на SASS сегодня, и появилось несколько проблем.

Не работает autofilename в файлах sass, в css файлах и html все отлично...

Emmet также отказывается нормально работать. К примеру df=display:flex в sass распаковывает совсем не то.

Использую Sublime. SASS расширение установил.

Answer (score 1):

1. Идешь по меню **Preferences -> Package Settings -> Emmet -> Settings - User**
2. Вставляешь туда:

```html
{
  "css_completions_scope": "source.css - meta.selector.css - meta.property-value.css, source.scss - meta.selector.scss - meta.property-value.scss - meta.poperty-list.css, source.less - meta.selector.css - meta.property-value.css, source.scss - meta.poperty-list.scss",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В предыдущем ответе ( @SashaOmelchenko ) в коде не хватает именно поддержки SASS :

Preferences -> Package Settings -> Emmet -> Settings-User

вставить строку (в последней части кода идёт SASS)

```
{
    "css_completions_scope": "source.css - meta.selector.css - meta.property-value.css, source.scss - meta.selector.scss - meta.property-value.scss, source.less - meta.selector.css - meta.property-value.css, source.sass - meta.selector.sass - meta.property-value.sass"
}
```

Comment: "В предыдущем ответе" -  укажите какой ответ вы имеете ввиду.Например "в ответе @SashaOmelchenko".